# How to build a static Clucene library to avoid any linker errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, cmake, clucene

I work with Windovs and I need to build a static CLucene library. I downloaded the latest source code and build them into Visual Studio 2010 Project through CMake-gui 3.4.3. When building I used a flag BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARIES = true. I successfully built two libraries: clucene-core-statics and clucene-shared-static. However, when I run the test project cl-test-static occurs a lot of linker errors. The same thing happens when I add these libraries in another test project.

Error Example:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: static wchar_t * __cdecl
>   lucene::queryParser::QueryParser::escape(wchar_t const *)"
>   (__imp_?escape@QueryParser@queryParser@lucene@@SAPA_WPB_W@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Main::Start(void)"
>   (?Start@Main@@QAEXXZ) c:\Users\user\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TestClucene\TestClucene\Main.obj    TestClucene

Does anyone have any experience in building static CLucene libraries?